# How to properly generate a variable string pattern in Python

Tags: python

I have managed to code a little snippet in Python which generates a character strip whose length equals the length of another string like so:

```
title = "This is a string"
concat_str = ""
for i in range (0,len(title)): #len(title) == 16
  concat_str += '-'
# resulting string
print(concat_str) # ----------------
```

Nevertheless, I wish to know whether this is the most pythonic way to implement this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that `+=` on strings in loops is `O(n²)` and should thus be avoided. Although trivial answers exist for this, the typical transformation would be to make a list and call `.append` in the loop. Then do a `"".join` afterwards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most pythonic way would be:

```
concat_str = '-' * len(title)
```

---

P.S. You do not need to specify `0` as the start for range: `range(len(title))` is more Pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to replace all characters with a dash:

```
concat_str = re.sub('.', '-', title)
```

Comment: You could - but why'd you want to get a regex engine involved in something so simple that can be achieved by Antti's answer that'll be faster and involve less overhead?

Comment: @JonClements The beauty of programming is the multitude of solutions, I just wanted to mention another. Otherwise, I would have simply repeated Antii.

Comment: Guess we could throw in `concat_str = ''.join('-' for ch in title)` then :p

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: the beauty of programming *in Python* is that there should be one obvious way to do it.  #Zen